# Get Paypal parameters in cancel_return

Tags: paypal

I want to get a parameter from Paypal which I am sending in 'custom' named hidden field. I can get the same on success page but not in cancel page. Does it need some efforts or Paypal do not provide any value on cancel page?

Answer (score 0):

Which language are you using to Integrate paypal?

I am using Java application. And I can tell you how I have approached this one. And I used Paypal Payments Pro Hosted Checkout solution. I guess you are using the same too.

Logging into the manager paypal account,  we can actually configure the Success, Failure and Cancel url.

For example let us say the below are the urls we have configured

```
paySuccessUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/paySuccess.htm";
payFailureUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/payFailure.htm";
payCancelUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/payFailure.htm";
```

We can only have one url for success, one for failure and one for cancel. But actually since the user can initiate payment transaction in various pages, it will be difficult for us to have only one single url per status.

So to approach this, I put the urls in the Java Session object.

For example : if user is in page a and initiated a payment transaction , what I typically do is

```
url a : http://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/a.htm
String successUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/eccommerce/successA.htm";
String failureUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/failureA.htm";
String cancelUrl = "http://mywebiste.com/ecommerce/cancelA.htm";
// Here append as many no of parameters as you wish 
Example : cancelUrl = cancelUrl + "prm1=" + val1 + "&par2=" + val2;

For url b 
// url b : http://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/b.htm
// String successUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/eccommerce/successB.htm";
// String failureUrl = "http://mywebsite.com/ecommerce/failureB.htm";
// String cancelUrl = "http://mywebiste.com/ecommerce/cancelB.htm";

HttpSessionn session = (HttpSession)request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("successUrl", successUrl);
session.setAttribute("failureUrl", failureUrl);
session.setAttribute("cancelUrl", cancelUrl);

So if pay is success

@RequestMapping("paySuccess.htm")
public void paySuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Do some processing
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession(true);
    String successUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("successUrl");
    response.sendRedirect(successUrl);
    // which intern call "http://mywebsite.com/eccommerce/successA.htm" url
    // or "http://mywebsite.com/eccommerce/successB.htm"
}

So if pay is failed then

@RequestMapping("payFailure.htm")
public void paySuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Do some processing
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession(true);
    String failureUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("failureUrl");
    response.sendRedirect(failureUrl);
    // which intern call "http://mywebsite.com/eccommerce/failureA.htm" url
    // or "http://mywebsite.com/eccommerce/failureB.htm"
}

And similarly for the pay cancel url

@RequestMapping("payCancel.htm")
public void paySuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Do some processing
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession(true);
    String cancelUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("cancelUrl");
    response.sendRedirect(cancelUrl);
    // which intern call "http://mywebsite.com/eccommerce/cancelA.htm" url
    // or "http://mywebsite.com/eccommerce/cancelB.htm"
}
```

So this way you don't need to send any custom parameters to paypal and expect paypal to send them back.

You can have your own cacel url in the session object with as many number of parameters appended as you wish.

I hope this helps you.